# what are dump and auxillary files?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dump

Im a newcommer to Linux and the gcc commands. I was reading the
[gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/index.html#SEC_Contents) particularly about the [-o flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-output-file-option) where it mentions the following:

> Though -o names only the primary output, it also affects the naming of
> **auxiliary** and **dump** outputs. See the examples below. Unless overridden,
> both auxiliary outputs and dump outputs are placed in the same
> directory as the primary output. In auxiliary outputs, the suffix of
> the input file is replaced with that of the ...

They mention it quite a lot following this paragraph but don't explain it. I've skimmed the document and also looked online but haven't found any satisfactory explanation. If someone could provide me some explanation or even link me to some resources where I can learn about these terms it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what exactly you do not understand / is not explained for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-o file
Place the output in file. This applies regardless of the type of output produced, whether it is an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
Since only one output file can be specified, it makes no sense to use -o when compiling more than one input file, unless you want to output an executable file.

If -o is not specified, the default behavior is to produce an executable file named a.out, an object file for source.suffix named source.o, its assembler file in source.s, and all C source code preprocessed on standard output.

source: http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/gcc/

hope it will be useful